# Regex: combination of integers, decimals, ranges and fractions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling to build a Regex which validates integers, decimals, fractions, ranges, as well as complex combinations of integers and ranges or fractions.

So far, with the help of another StackOverflow question, I've come up with this:

```
/^(?:(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:[.,]\d+)?|([1-9]\s)?([1-9]\d*[/-][1-9]\d*-?)+)$/
```

This validates:

- Integers without leading zeros (01 is invalid)
- Decimals with only one leadig zero (001,2 is invalid)
- Fractions without decimals (1/2 is valid, but 1,2/2,4 isn't).
- Ranges without decimals (1-2 is valid, but 1,2-2,4 isn't)
- Combinations of one digit units and fractions or ranges (1 1/2). For units, the integer rules apply (no commas, etc).
- Combinations of ranges and fractions (1/2-1/4 is valid, but 1/2- shouldn't be)

But I'm having trouble validating some complex combinations of integers and ranges which contain integers with fractions. For instance, this should also valid:

```
1-1 1/2
```

Using my current regex, how could I validate this part?

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a sidenote, you have an unescaped forward slash in there

Comment: I [tried](https://regex101.com/r/b85WIJ/3) your regex and it didnt match `1-1 1/2`.  But there are many case left that 's the regex wrong. Please update the question if you want to fix it.

Comment: @namgold I don't think I understand you, which cases are wrong? It works fine for all the cases in the bullet list, it's been throughly tested.

Comment: What about 10 1/2

Comment: @Koen oh, ok, we are only allowing one digit when combining integers with fractions, I'll edit the question :)

Comment: Ok, what about 1 1-2 which is valid (but shouldn't be?)

Comment: @Koen 1 1-2 is perfectly valid, why it shouldn't be?

Comment: It's hard to deduce from just the question, my bad

Comment: @Carlos So it is single digit units only when combining with ranges of fractions? Like `1 1-2` or `1-2 1`

Comment: Should these be valid or invalid? `1 1/10` and `1 1/2-`

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, using a single digit before the range or fraction is valid. So 1 1-2 or 1 1/2 are valid. Using it after the range or fraction isn't, so 1-2 1 or 1/2 1 isn't valid. It is also valid to use a one digit integer in the left side of the range, and a combination of a single digit and a fraction in the right side of the range. Since this is hard to read, and example is: 1 - 1 1/2

Comment: @Koen 1 1/10 is valid, 1 1/2- isn't

Comment: Are `0/5`, `2/0`, `2/2-4,2` valid?

Comment: @namgold no, these are not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current pattern validates a single requirement, you can optionally repeat it preceded by a space.

```
^(?:(?:[1-9]\d+|[1-9]\d*[/-][1-9]\d*|(?:0|[1-9]\d*),\d+)|[1-9](?:[/-][1-9]\d*)?(?:[ -][1-9][/-][1-9]\d*)?)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:` non capture group

    - `[1-9]\d+` Match a digit 1-9 and 1+ times a digit 0-9
    - `|` Or
    - `[1-9]\d*[/-][1-9]\d*`
    - `|` or
    - `(?:0|[1-9]\d*),\d+` Match either 0 or a digit 1-9 and optional
      digits followed by `,` and 1+ digits
  - `)` close non capture group
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9]` Match a single digit 1-9
  - `(?:[/-][1-9]\d*)?` Optionally match `/` or `-` and a digit 1-9 followed by optional digits
  - `(?:[ -][1-9][/-][1-9]\d*)?` Optionally match either a space or `-` and then a digit 1-9, either `/` or `-`, then a digit 1-9 and optional digits 0-9
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/caLF1K/1)

Comment: What about 10 1/2? *Evil laugh*

Comment: @Koen Do you mean that it should only be 1 digit units?

Comment: Yes, see the comments under the original question

Comment: this fails for 0,5 _Thinking face_

Comment: @Carlos You can match it like this https://regex101.com/r/yJVoN2/1

Comment: @Carlos How about this https://regex101.com/r/ZdvlZe/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird almost, but ,5 or 01,2 shouldn't be valid. I have tweaked it like so https://regex101.com/r/ZdvlZe/1. Still passes ,5 as valid (I'm running it against like 60 unit tests)

Comment: Or match either a 0 or a digit 1-9 https://regex101.com/r/U2rHqm/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird seems working fine, let me write some more unit tests and I'll mark the answer as accepted. Thanks a lot, you are truly a regex master! :)

Comment: @Carlos I have updated the answer with the latest pattern. Let me know if it works or if it needs some more work.

Comment: What about 2-1-2 ?